# How can I configure the OpenIddict to include the "iat" claim in the access token?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, openid-connect, openiddict

I'm using the AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server (OpenIddict) in a .NET Framework 4.8 application.

Here's the middleware options:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(options =>
{
    options.Issuer = new Uri(Config.IssuerUrl);
    options.AllowInsecureHttp = false;
    options.ApplicationCanDisplayErrors = true;
    options.TokenEndpointPath = new PathString(Paths.TokenPath);
    options.AuthorizationEndpointPath = new PathString(Paths.AuthorizePath);
    options.UserinfoEndpointPath = new PathString(Paths.UserInfoPath);
    options.LogoutEndpointPath = new PathString(Paths.LogoutPath);
    options.SigningCredentials.AddCertificate(certificate);
    options.Provider = new OpenIdConnectServerProvider();
    options.AccessTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    options.AccessTokenLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.UseSlidingExpiration = true;
});
```

The access token generated doesn't include the "iat" (issued at) claim. How can I configure the middleware to include this claim?

Or do I need to set this somehow on the client requesting the token?
One client application is an ASP.NET MVC applicaton using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server` is not OpenIddict: it was used as the low-level stack for OpenIddict in OpenIddict 1.x and 2.x but the project was merged into OpenIddict as part of the 3.x effort and was obsoleted a while ago.

The recent versions of OpenIddict automatically add an `iat` claim for you in JWT access tokens.